# Sideloaded windows store app needs a machine-wide setting

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, settings, windows-8.1, sideloading

We're developing a Line-of-business Windows Store App (8.1) that we're deploying via the sideloading process - but we need to include a "system wide" setting (in this case, the address of the database server as a URI)

We don't want to have the end users setting this through the app (as this would need to be in the user-specific local or roaming settings) - ideally we'd want to set this up as the application is deployed to the machine,  as different installations of the product will need different database strings.

In the Windows-Forms world, we'd use an app.config in the application's program files folder, but as far as I can see from MSDN there's no equivalent of this in the sandbox of the Windows Store as the apps are installed into a structure under the \Users\[username]
folder structure

We've though of a few things which are all a bit clunky...

- hard coding the address and doing a new build for each customer deployment
- hard coding an address and using a DNS remapping to point to the real server name (can't cope if we need to change the port number)
- allowing end users access to the setting through the settings charm and storing it per-user

Has anyone else solved this problem and come up with a way of either setting this during deployment, or via another mechanism to get the setting into each users sandbox'd install of the Windows 8 app.

Comment: I'd opt for the "branch for each customer" option, in case you need one PC to have multiple apps

Comment: I'd not thought of that, but it's a nice (and fairly neat way) to execute the "new build for each deployment" option.  Thanks :)

Comment: Up until the point you need to merge to a thousand branches, but if you're sideloading, I would assume the volume would be manageable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to figure out such a scenario myself. I think I will not use the branching approach but a customer build using msbuild. You run msbuild with `/p:customer=customer1` and have in your project file an

`<ItemGroup Include='%(customer).config'>
  <Link>app.config</Link>
</ItemGroup>`

Then in your app you have a app.config file included that contains the content of each customers config.
If you have a new customer you just add another `newcustomer.config` file and build the app with `msbuild projecfile /p:customer=newcustomer` or have a clever batch msbuild that finds all *.config files and builds the projects for them.